# Can i call a method inside a class(subclass of UIView) from another class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

Its kinda weird but i am not able to call any method defined inside the class (having the drawRect method).
This is what i do inside a UIviewcontroller class with nib for UI:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.lineVar Start];
}
```

lineVar is an object of the class (which is a subclass of UIview) which has the function Start.

```
-(void)Start {
    NSLog(@"Hi...");
}
```

I never see the log message.

I have assigned the Class with Start method to a view which occupies some part of the screen with the UIviewcontroller class with the nib file.

I want a method to be called everytime the view (subclass of uiview) is visited.
It only has awakeFromNib which is called just the first time.  viewdidLoad would have done the trick but its not there by default.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure self.lineVar isn't nil when you call Start.  If it's failing silently, that's probably the issue.  You may have forgotten to connect the lineVar outlet in your NIB.

Comment: Yes self.lineVar is 0x0 ... But lineVar is not of the type IBOutlet.. I have declared it as DrawView *lineVar; .... So i am not sure how to connect it in NIB

Comment: Declare the property like this: `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DrawView *lineVar;`.  Then you should see the outlet in the NIB.

Comment: Thank you so much that works...  I was not aware that the object outlet needs to be connected in the NIB... Thanks